# There are no servelet mappings specified in web.xml for controller servelet

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, mapping

Hi I am trying to run my controller java but I am getting error of There are no servelet mappings specified in web.xml for controller servelet

I just wanted to ask how can to do servelet mapping I will really appreciate any advice thank you

here is my controller code

```
   package com.kb.model;

   import com.kb.model.tbl_batch;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
   import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

   @ManagedBean
   public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
    tbl_dao dao = new tbl_dao();
    ArrayList<tbl_batch> list = dao.getData();

    httpSession.setAttribute("studentDetails", list);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request
            .getRequestDispatcher("500kusers_hibernate.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}
}
```

this my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com          
/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>Pager Tag</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>500kusers_hibernate.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>

    <display-name>Controller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
 com.kb.model.Controller
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Please add error trace into question

Comment: I cant see the error because when I click run error message appear "There are no servelet mappings specified in web.xml for controller servelet"

Comment: Hope you are placing `web.xml` in right location

Comment: can i ask where should be the right position for web.xml ? thank you

Comment: it should be in your app's `WEB-INF`directory